SearchKit table display link is missing URL parameter
I have SearchKit searches/tables on cases that that use a link on the ID column. Some of them - I presume the ones that I built last - don't have URL parameter cid in it and thus lead to errors when editing the case from the summary view. Is the parameter missing on purpose and why are there different versions of the table display in the same release?
SearchKit table link configuration with cid parameter:

SearchKit table link configuration without cid parameter:

This question is a follow-up on DB Error: constraint violation on changing case status.

I'm not really sure how you created the first one but first make sure Case Clients is one of the table joins in your search criteria, and then in the dropdown instead of Zeige Fall choose "Other...", and then put in civicrm/contact/view/case?reset=1&action=view&cid=[Case_CaseContact_Contact_01.id]&id=[id]. The token for the contact id might be slightly different depending on your search - you can use the </> dropdown to select the correct token.

The first table was created a couple of months ago with a different CiviCRM version. The case client is included in the join. Building the link myself works but is more of a workaround to me. Can anybody reproduce this behaviour of the "Show Case" feature?

Searchkit has been known to generate wrong links for a long time (e.g. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2509). If manage case links ever had the cid I'm not sure when that was. I can see in 5.69 they don't. So I don't know when your working one was created. Does it have a created date in the main searchkit listing?

The working table display was created on 24. August 2023. Should I create a bug issue for this?

I looked at 5.65 which was the security release before Aug 2023. It seems there was no View Case option then so the only choice was to use Other and manually put in the link! So that must have been how you did it.

Maybe. I still don't get why there are two different versions of that feature in the current release.

I'm not sure there are since I don't think it's possible to create your first one from scratch in the latest, where there is nothing to the right of "open normally". It's probably just how it looks when you upgrade. From the list of searchkits if you choose export and then import it into another new install it probably shows the manually entered path.
